# How to fix flickering screen in a Slick game?

Tags: java, ubuntu, flicker, vsync

I'm writing a simple Mario-like game with the [Slick](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/) library, and I have problem with the game window flickering. I usually have an Eclipse window below it, and it seems to me that when Eclipse updates its screen, stuff is drawn over my game.

When I start the game, it displays:

```
INFO:Slick Build #274
INFO:LWJGL Version: 2.0b1
INFO:OriginalDisplayMode: 1280 x 1024 x 24 @60Hz
INFO:TargetDisplayMode: 1024 x 768 x 0 @0Hz
INFO:Starting display 1024x768
INFO:Use Java PNG Loader = true
INFO:Controllers not available
```

I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 on a Lenovo Thinkpad x100e. I noticed that this does not happen for my friends, so I suppose it may be a driver (flgrx) or windowmanager (metacity) issue, but I don't know how to check it to be sure. Or maybe it's something with vsync?

Any ideas? Thanks in advance :)